# How to get woocommerce cart item using REST API?

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I'm new to WordPress & Woocommerce and have been trying to get cart content using [cocart's](https://cocart.com) for a website running on a different domain to sync the cart between a Woocommerce website and a React Application

I've added some products in the cart from the shop website and calling the "mydomain.com/wp-json/cocart/v1/get-cart" REST API from Postman but getting an empty array in the response.

From their doc, they mentioned a ***Cart Key*** and ***Cookie: wp_cocart_session_***, but I'm confused on how to get the Cart Key.

Any kind of help will be highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

use this plugin

https://wordpress.org/plugins/cart-rest-api-for-woocommerce/

or you can save the product id in sqlite and fetch data from woocommerce rest api to every product in the sqlite database and count the total

Comment: are you try to make an android app or what? if android you can use include parameters https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#list-all-products   after that you save the products ids when click add to btn to sqlite database , if website sorry i cant help you but you can try using the plugin and you should know how to parse json and make http request already

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Cookies apparently need to be sent with the request as well as the cart_key.

I solved this by installing the Postman Interceptor browser extension.

In Postman, click "Cookies" and it should ask if you want to setup Interceptor for the domain that you are requesting from. It will install a browser extension and get the cookies and add them to your Postman requests.

Postman provides an assisted step-by-step setup of Interceptor and cookie capture, but to manually access cookie capture settings click the icon in the upper right of Postman that says "Capture requests and cookies with Postman". That's where those setting are.

More about Interceptor here: https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/capturing-request-data/interceptor/#installing-interceptor